# what is the difference between import statsmodels.api as sm and import statsmodels as sm?

Tags: python

when I import statsmodels.api as sm, and run `sm.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess`
Error occurs:
module 'statsmodels.nonparametric.api' has no attribute 'smoothers_lowess'
But import statsmodels as sm doesn't have this error.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess()
```

```py
import statsmodels as sm
sm.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess()
```

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.nonparametric.api' has no attribute 'smoothers_lowess'

Comment: `statsmodels.api` and `statsmodels` are two different modules, from two different files; they can be expected to have different contents.

Comment: import statsmodels as sm should use: sm.api.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess()

Answer (score 1):

- `import statsmodels as sm` makes your `sm` refer to [`statsmodels`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/__init__.py) -- which is to say, `statsmodels/__init__.py`.
- `import statsmodels.api as sm` makes your `sm` refer to [`statsmodels.api`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/api.py) -- which is to say, `statsmodels/api.py`.

Because these are different files, it is normal and expected for them to have different contents. Note that all content accessed through the `api` modules is *public* functionality, supported and stable across releases; if you use nonpublic functionality, your code may break in future releases.

The difference in rationale between the APIs is documented at https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/importpaths.html

Comment: THX! And statsmodels.api enbales python to import the modules faster than statsmodels?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! It helps me a lot!

Comment: The imports from modules (without leading underscore) are also public. The main difference is importing most of statsmodels at once in the `api`, versus importing just some specific functionality plus supporting code. E.g. `from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS` is public and recommended if all you need is ols, especially in library use.

Comment: @Josef, insofar as this answer is flagged community wiki, I don't claim any personal ownership in it, and don't get any rep from its upvotes; please feel encouraged to edit for accuracy/completeness.

Answer (score 0):

`statsmodels` now provides an explanation for these two import methods.
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html#import-paths-and-structure

- `import statsmodels.api as sm` is recommended for interactive use. This makes most functions and classes conveniently available within one or two levels, without making the `sm` namespace too crowded.
- `statsmodels` submodules are arranged by topic. Direct import of specific submodules help avoid importing unnecessary modules and commands.